# DDD - Should Entities Have Equality Comparers

Tags: domain-driven-design

Eric Evans in the [plural sight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xRCOKKUSp9s) video says "I've have come to believe that an entity shouldn't even have equality comparison".

Would that mean that entity need not have a required Id field( since its infrastructure concern). In what cases would an entity compare be required? Like he mentions in most cases it might not be needed.

[Edit] When i mentioned not requiring an Id it was w.r.t to constructing the entity i.e i can test my logic with just a new object( order = new Order) without passing a Guid or Id. There would be an Id for persistence ideally db generated.

Comment: After the edit: yes, you could instantiate a new entity without passing an ID. See my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically speaking an Entity should not care about its ID; there is not use-case that comes to my mind right now when an Entity would query or use its own ID.

However, its ID is used by the outside world. Almost any client code (Presentation, Application or Infrastructure) that uses an Entity would use its ID. Without an ID, the client code would not be able to locate an Entity in the collection of all Entities.

Even the Domain layer code uses that ID. For example, inside an Aggregate, the Aggregate root use an ID when it locates a nested Entity, even it is just a simple integer key.

UPDATE:
In the real world, you as a Human Entity, do you need your Social Security Number (or whatever ID you have) when you eat, drink, sleep or anything you do alone? No, it is somehow irrelevant to the *business rules* by which a Human organism works. The other Human Entities need you ID to differentiate you from the other.

Comment: What about the scenario where you add entities to a hashset? I have asked a question here if you would like to answer: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/191963/adding-entities-to-a-hashset-that-are-distinct-by-id.  +1.

Answer (score 0):

What Eric Evans is referring to is what an equality operator/method would mean and why you would be comparing two entities in the first place.  If you stick to attempting to not work with more than one aggregate within the same transaction it becomes even more odd to have two objects representing the same entity.

Having an equality operator/method to check the *technical/synthetic* key, or even business keys for that matter, is probably OK but *when* are you going to need that?

If you create two "empty", not-yet-keyed, instances of an entity and then have an equality operator/method then you need to apply quite a few rules to determine whether or not they are representing the same entity.  Perhaps social security/ID number?  Even so, it is still an odd thing to do.  Those "business" keys would probably be constrained values/columns in your data store in any event.

I don't think there is any mention of mot having some unique identification since that is what associates an entity with a life cycle.  I wouldn't forego an `Id` of sorts, no.